# Is there a windows provided function to get the file extension on Windows Phone 8 in C++?

Tags: c++, windows-phone-8

The title is the whole question: Is there a windows provided function to get the file extension on Windows Phone in C++?

[I looked at the FileType property in the StorageFile class, but it is not implemented.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.storage.storagefile.filetype.aspx) Is there any alternative, or we just roll our own?

Comment: I never took Windows 8 seriously, and this does reinforce it. They've made the UI similar on phone and desktop (bad idea) but failed to make the API identical (also a bad idea). Same API, specialized UI would be a winner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StorageFile.Name` has the extension included. Just take everything after the last `.`.

Comment: Yeah I guess I'll just write it myself, I just wanted to make sure there wasn't some API hiding in the docs somewhere.